# javascript for specific web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

currently I have different javascript onload commands for each of my web pages. Is it possible to compile all of them in one javascript file and assign the functions to a specific web page? I'm currently working with an ASP.net MVC project, so I load a Layout.html when I start my application. I guess what I want is to only have a single javascript file and load it in my layout.html, and when I open another page a specific javascript function will run.

Comment: How about making separate function for every webpage and attach it to <body onLoad="function"> ? This way whole javascript can stay in one file.

Comment: Without seeing a specific example of your code i.e. the way you are onloading at the moment, it is tricky to advise precisely -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach functions to body onLoad for every page.

Answer (score 0):

Load your script from Layout page and just set this layout page as layout in all other views.
You can load function from that script from any view page. you don't need to load script file on every page.